# Soma com javascript retornando valor errado

Tags: javascript

Tenho alguns campos na minha página e elas possuem valores, eu pego esses valores e somo, acontece que o valor fica errado, como eu pego eles do DOM e acaba vindo como string, eu converto em número, então invés de postar todo o código aqui, sai algo parecido com isso:

```
var valor = parseInt("3.50");
console.log(valor + valor);
```

O valor que eu esperava era 7.00, mas ele me retorna 6, ou seja, a soma parece estar errada. Obs: estou aprendendo ainda

Comment: Não tá somando errado, você que está convertendo de maneira errada. use parseFloat no lugar de parseInt

Comment: parse int vai te retornar apenas o valor inteiro, sem o decimal.

Comment: Veja a [documentação](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)

Comment: Nossa, deu certo, mas me retorna apenas o valor assim: 7, existe um jeito de retornado igual reais?

Comment: `parseInt`, como o nome diz, transforma o valor em INT, ou seja, um valor inteiro. Se tem um valor decimal, deve converter em `float`, com o `parseFloat`.

Comment: @OtavioFagundes utilize o campo de pesquisa do site, já existe perguntas relacionadas.

Comment: @OtavioFagundes seria assim: `valor.toLocaleString("pt-BR", { style: "currency" , currency:"BRL"});` lembrando que `valor` tem que ser convertido antes.

Comment: Deu certinho e ainda me trouxe o "R$" automaticamente, eu não sabia que o javascript tinha esse tipo de coisa

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var valor = parseFloat("3.50");
console.log(valor + valor);
```

Tu está transformando a string em Inteiro ela vai arredondar para baixo padrão, no caso tu pode arredondar para cima usando `Math.round()` ou como está usando numero Real usar o `parseFloat()`